# ImageMagick stretchable image

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing

In iOS there is a concept of *stretchable images*, i.e. a way to define regions of an image where the underlying image data can be duplicated in an aesthetically pleasing way:

[image]

Is there any way to specify this with ImageMagick's `resize` option (for instance as part of a composition operation)?

My final goal is to have this kind of overlay fit nicely to any aspect ratio of background picture:

[image]

Comment: Imagemagick is capable of using liquid rescale and I think it is built into later versions but there is no way to protect certain areas from stretching as there is in Gimp and Photoshop. https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#liquid-rescale There was a discussion about protecting "high energy" areas but it did not happen. I assume it needs to much input from the user to be used in the command line.

Comment: liquid rescale looks like it could maybe do the trick but I have not been able to find any doc on the implementation in imagemagick. Do you have pointers to such doc?

Comment: From what I remember it would be convert input -liquid-rescale new_widthxnew_height output